# PHP protect against coupon duplicate use

Tags: php, paypal

I have set up a small webshop using PayPal as the payment platform. I am in the process of adding a coupon system, but I recently got stuck.

I have a table containing the different coupons as well as a field for each coupon, containing the amount of uses that particular coupon has left.
Now, here comes the tricky part: I am trying to make a system that prevents people from using the same coupon code multiple times, by checking out at the same time. One solution to this, would be to remove 1 use from that coupon before sending them through to paypal.

So here is the actual question: If I subtract 1 use from the coupon before sending the buyer to PayPal, how do I add that use back to the coupon, if the buyer decides to not complete the transaction and just closes the payment window?

Comment: Im sorry, but why was my question downvoted? I would like to know what I did wrong for future questions.

Comment: I didn't downvote your question, but most probably it was downvoted because your question is more of a discussion, rather an actual question.

Comment: The question is clearly stated at the end.

Comment: Please provide the PayPal code. If you are using a payment gateway to process the payment, please tell us (e.g. Paymill, Braintree Payments)

Comment: You would need to build some sort of system to handle that.  For Example, WooCommerce automatically cancels a pending order that is in the system for some period of time.  You could build similar functionality into your system and when it cancels the order have it update any coupon that was used on it, too.

Answer (score 0):

you can have a look at `PAYMENTSTATUS` of `GetTransationDetails()`
if transaction failure occures you can add the coupon back

Comment: Im sorry, I dont see how that can solves my problem?

Comment: how you are sending to paypal .? .you can get transaction details if you use api

Comment: I am building a query with products and other information, and then send it on to paypal in form of a string.

Comment: so how you confirm transaction?

Comment: I am using the PayPal IPN.

Comment: still you can get transaction details

Comment: How? The IPN is sent after the payment has been processed. I need a way to know if the payment window was closed before the payment was made